# Canvas text justify with letter spacing text spacing - FabricJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way to justify words using letter spacing to a defined width, using FabricJS?

For example,

> わたしは
>
> すみません
>
> あぎがとう

would look, well, something like this:

[This is example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaN8D.png)

In Microsoft Word, it is called "Distributed". (Ctrl + Shift + J).

I am trying to add letterspacing feature to my project using fabricjs.

I can't find solution how to use letterspacing in fabricjs.

Comment: Surely if you just have a "fixed width font" then you just leave it as left aligned and it will provide that result

Comment: charspacing is built in fabricjs. what version are you using?

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Textbox.html#charSpacing

Comment: That effect is called justification, can't you use `textAlign: justify` ?

Comment: I used charSpacing. But when scale small, text will be moved line down

Comment: わたしは, It doesn't have space in between words, textAlign is useless

Comment: Could you share your code?